# How can I return data category in object form on the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

My table category like this :

[image]

I want to using laravel eloquent to select the data category and then it will return in a object form like this :

```
categories: [
    {
        name: 'England',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Chelsea',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Hazard'},
                    {name: 'Morata'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Manchester United',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Pogba'},
                    {name: 'Lukaku'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Spain',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Real Madrid',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Ronaldo'},
                    {name: 'Bale'}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Barcelona',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Messi'},
                    {name: 'Suarez'}
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Category` model with a `children` relationship:

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

Then you can query them like this:

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children.children')->get();
```